# ¿Como hacer una cadena de conexion a sql azure en windows form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, azure-sql

Lo que deseo hacer es un crud con una base de datos de sql azure con autenticación de active directory

Comment: Bienvenido @DannyLópez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), favoreciendo así tus chances de obtener una buena recepción por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar la autenticación de active directory con azure, no puedes utilizar el típico `Integrated security=true` (o SSPI).

En cambio la cadena de conexión debe incluir el segmento:

`Authentication=Active Directory Integrated`

Y ejecutarse desde un equipo unido al dominio.

Por ejemplo, una cadena de conexión completa luciría así:

```
cadena = 'Server=tcp:miservidor.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Database=miBaseDatos;';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me a sido muy útil

Comment: Me alegra que haya sido de utilidad. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, de esa manera futuros visitantes podrán ver que lo ha sido. Un saludo.